# Two-loops error using parfor in the external for

Tags: matlab, loops, parallel-processing, parfor

I need to parallelize a code in order to save time. I have a loop internal to another loop, and I would like to parallelize the external one (because I think it this way the code is faster). My code looks like this:

```
A = rand(1000,1);
B = rand(1000,1);
Biggers = zeros(1000,1000);
parfor i = 1:size(A,1)
    for j= 1:1:size(B,1)
        if B(i,1) > A(j,1) 
           Biggers(i,j) = A(j,1);
        end
     end
end
```

but if I run it this way I get the error:

```
Error: The variable Biggers in a parfor cannot be classified.   
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".
```

this condition does not occur if I instead parallelize the internal loop, i.e. if design the code as:

```
A = rand(1000,1);
B = rand(1000,1);
Biggers = zeros(1000,1000);
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    parfor j= 1:1:size(B,1)
        if B(i,1) > A(j,1)
            Biggers(i,j) = A(j,1);
        end
    end
end
```

I don't understand why in the first case `Biggers` is not considered a sliced variable, since every worker should focus only on a line of my variable.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to exactly why it does not work with the outer loop I am not sure. MATLAB has very strict regulations on what can and what can't go into the `parfor` loop which are not always crystal clear.

The "simple" solution would be to wrap everything you have *inside* your `parfor` loop into a function, then `parfor` suddenly eats everything. i.e.

```
function Biggers = parforfunc(A,B,ii)
for jj= 1:size(B,1)
    if B(ii,1) > A(jj,1) 
       Biggers(ii,jj) = A(jj,1);
    end
end
end
```

Save that as `parforfunc.m` and run your script with

```
A = rand(1000,1);
B = rand(1000,1);
Biggers = zeros(size(B,1),size(A,1));
parfor ii = 1:size(A,1)
    Biggers = parforfunc(A,B,ii);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

@Adriaan's answer solves the problem neatly - but if you're curious, the problem here is the "non-constant" bounds of the inner `for` loop. You and I can clearly see that the bounds of the inner `for` loop are constant in practice, but MATLAB's rules for `parfor` require that the bounds of any inner `for` loop are "broadcast" variables. So, the fix is trivial - hoist the inner loop bounds computation out of the `parfor` loop, like so:

```
A = rand(1000,1);
B = rand(1000,1);
Biggers = zeros(1000,1000);
n = size(B,1);
parfor i = 1:size(A,1)
    for j= 1:n
        if B(i,1) > A(j,1) 
           Biggers(i,j) = A(j,1);
        end
    end
end
```

This case is described [in the doc](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/nesting-and-flow-in-parfor-loops.html#bsz9hvi).