# How to append a matrix inside a WHILE loop that s nested iside a PARFOR loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, while-loop, nested-loops, parfor

I have a code that I use to compute the iterations needed to converge a number's Collatz sequence to one:

```
nums = input('Enter a number: ');

iter = zeros(1, nums, 'uint16');

collatz = zeros(1, nums, 'uint64');
seqn = zeros(nums, 'uint64');

parfor ii = 1:nums    

    num = ii;
    collatz(ii) = num;
    % seqn(ii) = num;

    while num ~= 1

        % writes the maximum number reached
        if collatz(ii) < num
            collatz(ii) = num; 
        end

        if rem(num, 2) == 0
            num = num / 2;
        else
            num = 3 * num + 1;
        end

        % counts iterations needed to reduce each number to one
        iter(ii) = iter(ii) + 1;

        % records the sequence
        seqn(:, iter(ii)) = num;

    end
end
```

Shortly, it computes the Collatz sequence for each number up to `num`, records the maximum number in the sequence, and records the number of iterations ot took to reduce the number to one.

With the `seqn` matrix, I'm trying to record the Collatz sequnece of each number I run the loop for.

The problem here is that MATLAB won't run this `PARFOR` loop because of the changes done to `seqn`. I don't understand the reason! It seems to me that what I do to `iter` is essentially the same thing I do to `seqn`, in the sense that it executes inside the nested `WHILE` loop and does not depend on previous iterations.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: [This answer by a MATLAB employee](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37696213/5211833) might help you, it looks like it's the same as what you want. General `parfor` tips can be found in [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146555/saving-time-and-memory-using-parfor-in-matlab/32146700#32146700). (I'll delete the other comments now, as I think half of them either wrong or covered by the answer here, and to clean up a bit)

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your while loop into for loop and set the final value of `iter` outside. additionally I'm only setting one element of `seqn` instead of entire column like you did. now matlab lets you run that but I'm not sure it's what you wanted, so take a look:

```
nums = input('Enter a number: ');

iter = zeros(1, nums, 'uint16');
maxitr = 1e6;
collatz = zeros(1, nums, 'uint64');
seqn = zeros(nums, 'uint64');

parfor ii = 1:nums

    num = ii;
    collatz(ii) = num;
    % seqn(ii) = num;

    for itr = 1:maxitr
        if num == 1
            break
        end
        % writes the maximum number reached
        if collatz(ii) < num
            collatz(ii) = num;
        end

        if rem(num, 2) == 0
            num = num / 2;
        else
            num = 3 * num + 1;
        end

        % records the sequence
        seqn(ii, itr) = num;
    end
    iter(ii) = itr - 1;
end
```

Comment: Great idea with the `for` loop instead of `while`! I rejected it initially because I didn't know how many iterations I'd need to do, but all evidence (numbers up to 10^8) shows that 10^6 would be more than enough. I'll check this when I have access to my machine and come back :)

Comment: ... aaaand my laptop almost crashed :D RAM usage went up to my maximum (8 Gb) - this doesn't hapen with my implementation. Can't see the reason though.

Comment: Oh, it's probably the preallocation - `uint32` and `uint64` eat too much RAM.